Ubuntu 24.04 + Iris Xe Graphics laggy whenever I have animations in Chrome on another Workspace
I recently bought a 12th gen Intel i5 with Iris Xe Graphics. I got a fresh Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on it:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator

I noticed my PC was laggy (2 second freezes) from time to time. Over time I realized it's whenever I have some websites open (with animations running or some react websites like lu.ma). If I find and close the window causing it, all is well.
I use some 6-10 workspaces at a time, often with an external screen. With Chrome windows on some 2 3 profiles. System Monitor reads 41.8GB of RAM, so I don't think that's the issue. I've never seen it at 50% even.

I'm pretty sure if I want to minimize this issue, if I leave the windows minimized on that workspace it doesn't happen. I can also notice, in that case, if I press the windows key to  zoom out between workspaces that window is no longer moving/animated.
